# Click Event in Class Module Not Firing

Tags: vba, excel, class, events

I have a user form that displays line-by-line validation errors (in text box) that I want to supplement with user form labels that act as hyperlinks that users can click to go directly to the cell with issues.

I have code that builds labels on the fly and have added a click event through class modules but I cannot get it the click event in the class module to fire.

I did modify this code from working code that builds this type of label and click event on the fly, but that code loads labels at userform initiation and places each class object into a collection. I don't know if that is necessary to build into my solution, but I played with it and could not get it to work.

Here is my procedure to place label on the userform if needed. It runs inside another procedure if validation is needed. Userform is than shown, filled out with message (and this one label that gets created for now), if validation is needed.

```
Sub PlaceLinkLabel(SayWhat As String, WhichSheet As String, WhichRange As String)

    Dim lblNew As MSForms.Label
    Set lblNew = frmValidationMessage.Controls.Add(bstrProgID:="Forms.Label.1", Name:=SayWhat, Visible:=True)

    With lblNew
        With .Font
            .Size = 10
            .Name = "Comic Sans MS"
        End With

        .Caption = SayWhat
        .Top = 55
        .Height = 15
        .Left = 465
        .Width = 100
    End With

    Dim clsLabel As UserFormLabelLinks
    Set clsLabel = New UserFormLabelLinks
    Set clsLabel.lbl = lblNew

    With clsLabel
        .WhichRange = WhichRange
        .WhichSheet = WhichSheet
    End With

    'not sure if this is needed or not
    'Dim pLabels As Collection
    'Set pLabels = New Collection
    'pLabels.Add clsLabel

End Sub
```

Here is `UserFormLabelLinks` class module:

```
Option Explicit

Private WithEvents pLabel As MSForms.Label
Private sWhichRange As String
Private sWhichSheet As String

Public Property Set lbl(value As MSForms.Label)
    Set pLabel = value
End Property

Public Property Get WhichSheet() As String
    WhichSheet = sWhichSheet
End Property

Public Property Let WhichSheet(value As String)
    sWhichSheet = value
End Property

Public Property Get WhichRange() As String
    WhichRange = sWhichRange
End Property

Public Property Let WhichRange(value As String)
    sWhichRange = value
End Property


Private Sub pLabel_Click()

    MsgBox "hi" 'when i click label, this does not fire

    'Application.Goto ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(WhichSheet).Range(WhichRange), True
    'ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink ("#" & WhichSheet & "!" & WhichRange)

End Sub
```

Comment: @Mat'sMug - Awesome. Glad my question could potentially improve some software :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `MSForms.Label` object is going out of scope as soon as `PlaceLinkLabel` exits, as does the `UserFormLabelLinks` object reference; thus you're creating a label, but it's a *fire-and-forget* thing that you can't programmatically access as soon as `End Sub` is reached, hence the events never fire.

You need a private field to hold on to the `UserFormLabelLinks` object reference (and thus keep the `MSForms.Label` reference around via the encapsulated `pLabel` field):

```
Option Explicit
Private clsLabel As UserFormLabelLinks
```

Then remove this line in the procedure:

> ```
> Dim clsLabel As UserFormLabelLinks
> ```

In other words, promote that local variable to a field, to keep it around after the procedure has completed.

Comment: I knew you would be right on top of this one. Thanks so much. I also found another way to make it work via collection right after I posted the question. I will throw that answer up too, just for information.

Comment: Yup. Storing the reference in a module-level collection will also keep it around. The idea is just to get the object reference to outlive the procedure =)

Comment: Yes. As as soon as I posted the question and looked at code again I understand immediately the problem (keeping the object around). It's like just asking the question provided the answer - which so often happens in life.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach that worked:

Placing 
`Private pLabels As Collection` atop the module where `PlaceLinkLabel` is stored

and using

```
If pLabels Is Nothing Then Set pLabels = New Collection
pLabels.Add clsLabel
```

at the end of `PlaceLinkLabel` module

Comment: Upovoted, but making that collection `Public` seems "dangerous" to me!

Comment: Yeah good point. Because another procedure module could accidentally access the collection correct?

Comment: And `Set` it to `Nothing`, or `Clear` it, or otherwise do something it shouldn't be allowed to do. Not that any sane developer would do that, but why even allow it in the first place?

Comment: @Mat'sMug - Interesting thing here is when I used your method and added more than one label only the last label added fired the code. When I used the collection method all the labels fired the code, which makes perfect sense actually. More putting this comment for others that may stumble on this question and may also being added multiple labels.