# Click Event in Class Module Not Firing 2.0

Tags: vba, class, module

I have a similar question as described in the follow link: [Click Event in Class Module Not Firing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46777898/click-event-in-class-module-not-firing)

(Don't have the rep to comment there and ask for clarification, so made a new question)

My set up is as follows:

Userform_Initialize makes a Call to a Sub in a Module that creates ComboBoxes for this Userform, these ComboBoxes get set to a Class Module.

If I understand the answer given in the link correctly, the connection between the ComboBox and the Class Module is forgotten before the userform is shown and therefore the action doesn't fire. Unfortunately, I can't get it to work.

I was wondering if someone could specify the answer given in the link. Where do I put the "Option Explicit" and "Private clsLabel As UserFormLabelLink"? I've tried several locations, but every time I get a different error (Compile errors).

(When I put a UserForm.Show in the module, which creates those ComboBoxes, the action does fire, but this creates an 91 Error at a later stage of the Userform.)

If someone could help it would be much appreciated!

EDIT - Here's the code

Module

```
Dim inputComboH As cComboHandler
Set collInputCombo = New Collection
Dim userformCombo As ComboBox

Set userformCombo = UserForm1.MultiPage1.Page1.Controls("Frame1").Add("Forms.ComboBox.1")
            With userformCombo
                .Name = "ComboBox"
                'Add items to the combobox
                For k = 0 To 5
                    .AddItem "Item" & k
                Next k


                    Set inputComboH = New cComboHandler
                    Set inputComboH.inputComboH = userformCombo
                    collInputCombo.Add inputComboH


            End With
```

Class Module cComboHandler

```
Public WithEvents inputComboH As MSForms.ComboBox
Public Sub inputComboH_Click()
    MsgBox "Clicked"
End Sub
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you post your code. Please review [ask]

Comment: Hi Aron, made and edit

Answer (score 0):

`Option Explicit` should be placed at the top of every module/class.  It prevents you from using undeclared variables.  Without `Option Explicit` this code is valid.

```
Sub Example1()

    ' Ctrl + G will open the immediate window, if closed.
    ' You'll need this to view the output.
    myMessage = "Hello World"
    Debug.Print myMessage
End Sub
```

Although you never explicitly declare `myMessage` it is created for you.

Adding `Option Explicit` prevents the same code from running.  You'll get an error:

> Compile error:
>
> Variable not defined

```
Option Explicit

Sub Example1()

    ' To fix add "Dim myMessage As String" above this line.
    ' The next line is responsible for the error.
    myMessage = "Hello World"
    Debug.Print myMessage
End Sub
```

This helps you to avoid subtle errors.  In this example, without option explicit, a typo creates two variables.

```
' myCounter and myCount are meant to be the same
' variable.  The user forgot/mistyped the name the
' second time around, leading to an infinite loop.
'
' You can run this code.
' Press Cntrl + Break to pause/reset to stop.
Sub Exmaple2()

    myCounter = 1
    Do
        Debug.Print myCounter
        myCount = myCount + 1    ' This line contains our "error"
        DoEvents
    Loop Until myCounter = 100
End Sub
```

You can automatically add option explicit to every module (which is a good idea) from the options menu (Tools >> Options >> Require Variable Declaration).

Your second question is about [scope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)).  Scope controls how variables can be accessed, and long they live for.  A variable leaves scope when then is no longer a valid way to access it.  At this point, the variable is destroyed (that might not always be technically true but for practical pruposes this is ok).

Variables declared within a sub/function have local scope.  That means they can only be accessed only within the declaring procedure.  When the procedure ends they can no longer be accessed and so are destroyed.  Once destroyed any value they held is lost (this is why your events won't fire - the objects that contain the events are lost).

```
' At the end of this sub, i will always equal 1,
' regardless of the number of times you execute it.
' This is because i is created each time you call the sub, and destroyed when it ends.
' Each new verson of i has a default value of 0, to which we add one.
Sub Example2()

    Dim i As Integer
    i = i + 1
    Debug.Print i
End Sub
```

Now let's declare `i` at the module/class level.  With module scope, the variable will survive until the entire module leaves scope.  That will occur when:

- The user presses reset.
- The `End` command is encountered.
- The parent workbook is closed.
- In the case of classes; the class leaves scope.

Example:

```
' i is declared at the module/class level.
' It's value is maintained between calls to Example3.
Private i As Integer

' Each call to this sub will increment i by 1.
' Call 1 will output 1.
' Call 2 will output 2.
' etc
Sub Example3()

    i = i + 1
    Debug.Print i
End Sub
```

Scope is a big topic and can be confusing at first. Most [VBA books](https://www.amazon.co.uk/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=wrox+vba&rh=i%3Aaps%2Ck%3Awrox+vba) cover this.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @destination-data much apreciated

Comment: could you elaborate a bit further concerning my data? I'm assuming I should increase the scope of inputComboH, but where do I do this?

Again, the Userform_initialize calls the module that assigns the class module.

Should I also change the scope of the Sub?

Comment: Because `collInputCombo` contains all of your `inputComboH` classes it is important that remains in scope.  The moment VBA destroys it you will lose your classes, and their events.  Declare `collInputCombo` outside of any subs/funcs.  Example: `Private collInputCombo As Collection`.  Assuming this is inside a module.  If in a class it can be more complex.